# URL Hacking: Make a field required

Tags: urlhacking

Because I can't customized the convert lead layout I would like to use a URL hack of some sort to pass a value through that then makes the 'Due Date' field required. Is this possible?

Comment: Nope. And even if the hack existed it would absolutely not be supported/reliable.

Comment: one silly way i can think of is to provide a fake text like" Enter a valid date to proceed" as value to the date field in your URL hack, this way the page wont save and you have a way to force the user to enter a date field. Not recommendtingthis as the best solution but if you can live with it might just do the job.

Comment: @Rao I like that workaround, the only thing I don't like is that it will throw an error as soon as the page is loaded, do you know if there is a way I could refrain from getting the error until after they click submit?

Comment: @Brohibition it gets too complicated when you try to keep it nice 1) Salesforce has enabled click jack, if you can risk it all and disable click jack protection you contact support disable the feature and embed the lead convert page as iframe and use JS in the same VF page and check if the duedate is not empty. 2) You can create your own VF replica of convert page (or) install some appexchange products to do the same and validate the field